# How do I parse the data hidden inside html code using bs4

Tags: beautifulsoup

I need to parse this number from a website that has been updated. I cannot access the data-component part of the html code.

[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q0J0.png)

I've tried xpath parsing and bs4

```
url = "https://www.muthead.com/20/players/10111309/upgrades/"
r = requests.get(url)
content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
hello = soup.find("div",class_="average rating-list__RatingValue-ubw14i-3 jzOWLB").text
print(hello)
```

I get the following error:

```
hello = soup.find("div",class_="average rating-list__RatingValue-ubw14i-3 jzOWLB").text
builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I need to scrape the `77`inside the html code inside the dic `class= average rating-list__RatingValue-ubw14i-3 jzOWLB> 77 </div>`

It seems like bs4 can't look inside the main container i get no code after

```
 <div data-component="player-upgrades" data-props="{externalId": 10111309, "gameSlug": "20", "basePath": "/20/players/10111309/upgrades/"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The content on the website is rendered using javascript so you there is barely any use in using `BeautifulSoup` in your case. That being said I would recommend getting all of the player stats directly from the API by using the following code:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.muthead.com/api/mutdb/player_item/?expand=game%2Cposition%2Cprogram%2Cteam%2Cupgrade_tiers&external_id=10111309&game__slug=20"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"}

req_raw = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
spd = req_raw["results"][0]["stats"][1]["value"]

print(spd)
```

Alternatively, if you are planning to use many links you might want to use the following code:

```
import requests

url_raw = "https://www.muthead.com/20/players/10111309/upgrades/"

external_id = url_raw.split("/")[5]
game_slug = url_raw.split("/")[3]

url = "https://www.muthead.com/api/mutdb/player_item/?expand=game%2Cposition%2Cprogram%2Cteam%2Cupgrade_tiers&external_id={}&game__slug={}".format(external_id, game_slug)

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"}

req_raw = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
spd = req_raw["results"][0]["stats"][1]["value"]

print(spd)
```

where you just need to replace `url_raw` with the URL of the game you are **scraping** and the script will automatically send a request to the API (without you having to find the API link)

*(do note both codes output `77`)*

Hope this helps!